# Optional Params in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function:

```
public static async myFunc(
    x: 500,
    y: boolean = true,
    z = 1000,
)
```

I want to call the function without passing in `y`

```
myFunc(1000, 2000);
```

But getting an error that 2000 is not a boolean

Comment: that won't be valid declaration of the function in **javascript**, will it? try `myFunc(1000, undefined, 2000);` - funciton arguments are positional - even with defaults

Comment: Man is this even javasctipt?

Comment: @AdilBimzagh it isn't. It's most likely TypeScript but it might also be Flow.

Comment: You can change the order of the arguments and make it `myFunc(x, z, y) {}` and this way you can call it like this `myFunc(1000, 2000)`

Answer (score 0):

What about using object destructuring:

```js
function myFunc({
    x = 500,
    y = true,
    z = 1000,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass object as argument into your function.

```
const myFunc = ({ x, y, z }) => {
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
  console.log(z);
};

myFunc({ x: 500, y: false, z: 1000 });
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tjzw6n?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.js)